csrf mismatch with angular 17
I'm trying to create a login page using angular 17 and laravel 11 sanctum, but i get csrf mismatch problem:
env file:
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

config/sanctum.php
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    '%s%s',
    'localhost,localhost:3000,localhost:4200,localhost:8000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
    Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
))),

login.component.ts
  login(e:Event){
    this.authservice.getCsrfToken().subscribe(
      {next: () => {
        this.authservice.login(this.formGroup.value).subscribe({
          next: (response:any) => console.log(response),
          error: (err:any) => {console.log(err)}
        });
      }
    });
  }

authservice
here for some reson my angular httpclient doesn't send xsrf token in login request header so i had to send it manually
 headers = new HttpHeaders();

  private setHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers =  headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers =  headers.set('Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    headers =  headers.set("X-XSRF-TOKEN", this.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN'));
    return headers;
  }

  getCookie(name: string): string{
    const ca: Array<string> = document.cookie.split(';');
    const cookieName = `${name}=`;
    for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      let c = ca[i].trim();
      if (c.indexOf(cookieName) == 0) {
        return c.substring(cookieName.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
  private userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getCsrfToken() : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie", {withCredentials : true});
  }
  login(data: any) : Observable<any>{
    const headers = this.setHeaders();

    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/api/login",data, {headers: headers,  withCredentials : true});
  }

in config/cores
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,

and i added this code to my bootstrap/app.php:
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
->withRouting(
    web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
    api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
    commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
    health: '/up',
)
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->statefulApi();
})
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    //
})->create();

i can see the cookie in my browser and x-xsrf-token in my request header

Could you share your entire middleware pipeline? The order does matter there. I can't see what's wrong. As a reference here's how we do it in ASP.NET Core...

@Pieterjan thank you for your comment, i've updated the code above, i included the whole code in bootstrap/app.php. and do i have to change my config/auth.php? the code there is by default
